# installation of flashplugin-installer is failing

Tags: flash, adobe

I would like to install `flashplugin-installer` but I get the following:

```
ron@jpax-build11:~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  x-ttcidfont-conf ttf-mscorefonts-installer ttf-bitstream-vera ttf-dejavu
  ttf-xfree86-nonfree xfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flashplugin-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,866 B of archives.
After this operation, 140 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package flashplugin-installer.
(Reading database ... 445615 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (0.154.1ubuntu1) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20150811.1.orig.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 239, in process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
ron@jpax-build11:~$
```

But I can download http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20150811.1.orig.tar.gz just fine with `wget` but I don't know how to install it after. How can I get this going?

Thanks

**EDIT1**
Not sure which version of Ubuntu, I think it's version **12.04** (due to compatibility reasons)

```
$ apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer
flashplugin-installer:
  Installed: 11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 11.2.202.508ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.202.350ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
ron@jpax-build11:~$
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? What does `apt-cache policy flashplugin-installer` say?

Comment: @muru Please see **EDIT 1** above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but looking at the `postinst` script, the file is supposed to be in `/var/cache/flashplugin-installer`. Try keeping the file there and running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure flashplugin-installer`:

```
sudo cp adobe-flashplugin_20150811.1.orig.tar.gz /var/cache/flashplugin-installer
sudo dpkg-reconfigure flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: That's it, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure flashplugin-installer` got me going! Thanks!